# JAXB binding for JAX-WS SOAP request body parameters

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm writing a SOAP web service for [Windows Phone 8(WP8) Enterprise MDM](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/C/4/5C460CE2-3B0F-45CE-805D-1A3D5697639C/WP8_Enterprise_Device_Management_Protocol.pdf&ei=DESYU--ECZC5uATG34CQDA&usg=AFQjCNE7fEvr5RxwEYJWxPA-PqNsKZ5r4A&bvm=bv.68693194,d.c2E) in java. The client was WP8, and it's SOAP request will be like following, and I have no right to change anything on this request.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/IDiscoveryService/Discover</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid: 748132ec-a575-4329-b01b-6171a9cf8478</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://ENROLLTEST.CONTOSO.COM/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc</a:To>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <Discover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/">
         <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <EmailAddress>user@contoso.com</EmailAddress>
            <RequestVersion>1.0</RequestVersion>
         </request>
      </Discover>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Following is my service class,

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@Addressing(enabled=true, required=true)
public interface DiscoveryService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "Discover")
    SOAPMessage handleDiscoveryRequest(@WebParam(name = "request",targetNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
                                       DiscoveryRequest request) throws Exception;
}
```

And the request body xml mapping class,

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DiscoveryRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "EmailAddress", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    private String emailId;

    @XmlElement(name = "RequestVersion", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    private String version;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

However, from the SOAP-UI, I got the following sample request with generated WSDL

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:enr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <enr:Discover>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsi:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsi:EmailAddress>?</xsi:EmailAddress>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsi:RequestVersion>?</xsi:RequestVersion>
         </xsi:request>
      </enr:Discover>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And, When I send the intended request (first code snap), I got the following error response in SOAP-UI

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
      <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/DiscoveryService/Discover/Fault/UnmarshalException</Action>
      <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:d81dbc0f-cbd4-41dc-aa62-aed06f3c2dc6</MessageID>
      <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</To>
      <RelatesTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid: 748132ec-a575-4329-b01b-6171a9cf8478</RelatesTo>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/", local:"request"). Expected elements are &lt;{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}request></soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help on how to fix this JAXB binding namespace issue?

```
Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/", local:"request"). Expected elements are &lt;{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}request
```

Answer (score 2):

The example request and the mappings do not match.

In the first request the element 'request' is in '.../enrollment' namespace. Despite the xmlns:i is defined for it, the prefix is not set, so it inherits the default namespace, which is set at parent:

```
<Discover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/">
     <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So the error message is totally correct.

To make that example request to match your intentions (and to match WSDL), you should have

```
     <i:request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Note 'i:' prefix.

If the request is canonical (i.e. it is a right request provided as an example), then you should update your mapping, obviously, i.e. remove XMLSchema-instance as a targetNamespace.

The rest seems OK at a casual look. Generally, when dealing with SOAP, I suggest to provide the WSDL, too.

Comment: I can't change the request. It's defined by WP8. Can you please elaborate more on the removing target name space?

Comment: Look at your service class and mapping: everywhere you see XMLSchema-instance, remove it and replace with '.../enrollment' namespace. Elements 'request', 'EmailAddress' and 'RequestVersion' must be in 'enrollment' namespace, specifically.

Comment: Ok, I did that, Now I'm getting, `Action http://api.agent.windows.wso2.org/DiscoveryService/DiscoverRequest not supported` error

Comment: See those mustUnderstand="1" headers in the example request? You have to support them in you service. You need to implement SOAPHandler and consume those headers. See here: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/working-with-headers-in-jax-ws-soaphandlers/